# Defining names of list elements

Tags: r, list, loops, vector, naming

Let's consider vector of names for the elements of my list:

```
name_vec <- c("name", "of", "the", "list", "elements")
```

This vector contains names of the elements of the list. Let's define an empty list and name each element with elements from `name_vec`

```
my_list <- list()

for (i in seq_len(length(name_vec))) { 
  my_list[[name_vec[i]]] <- i+1
}
```

However I find this solution highly inefficient due to fact that loop was used. I think that has to be some way to avoid it but I'm not aware of it. Tried to do something with `lapply` but it lead's me to nothing. Do you have any ideas how it can be done ?

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
as.list(setNames(seq_along(name_vec) + 1, name_vec))

$name
[1] 2

$of
[1] 3

$the
[1] 4

$list
[1] 5

$elements
[1] 6
```

The results are the same:

```
identical(my_list, as.list(setNames(seq_along(name_vec) + 1, name_vec)))

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or `setNames(as.list(seq_along(name_vec) + 1), name_vec)`, swapping `as.list` and `setNames`, also with identical result.